# Combinatorics problem. Are these two approaches equivalent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem goes like this: 7 accidents ocurred in a week, what is the probability that 2 days of the week had 2 accidents each and 3 days had 1 accident each.

So I thought about this in two different ways, getting two different results.

1st approach: I assign a number of accidents to each day of the week. The sample space consists of sequences like $100024$ which means $1$ accident on Sunday, $2$ on Friday and $4$ on Saturday. I will omit my calculations for now, but I got $1716$ of these sequences. Favorable cases are the permutations of $2211100$, and I got $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!} = 210$ of them. The probability is therefore $\frac{210}{1716} \simeq 0.122$

2nd approach: I have a sequence of accidents $a_1, ...,  a_7$ and I assign a day of the week to each of them. The sample space consists of sequences like $Su, Mo, Su, Th, W, W, Su$ which means that $3$ accidents ocurred on Sunday, $1$ on Monday, $1$ on Thursday, $2$ on Wednesday. There are $7^7$ of this sequences, and favorable cases are $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!} \frac{7!}{2!2!1!1!1!0!0!}$. The probability is therefore $\simeq 0,321$.

Although it is certainly possible that I got my calculations wrong, I don't believe so because I simulated each approach in Python, and computer results agree with my own calculations. I think that there is a conceptual difference between these two approaches that I am not seeing. Are these approaches equivalent?

Comment: Without any further data, one way to look at it will be that an accident can occur any day of the week with equal probability, which is $\frac{1}{7}$ and that each accident is an independent event.

Comment: @Math Lover yes, I guess that that is essentially my second approach

Comment: @Javi: Your first approach is correct. How are you counting the favorable cases in your second approach?

Comment: @Brian I divide the $7$ days into $3$ groups (1st group having $2$ days with $2$ accidents each; 2nd group having $3$ days with $1$ accident each, and 3rd group having $2$ days with no accidents). There are therefore $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}$ ways to form this groups. For each of those ways, I can arrange the days in $\frac{7!}{2!2!1!1!1!0!0!}$ ways, which correspond to the permutations, for example, of the favorable case $Su, Su, Mo, Mo, Tue, Tue, Tue$

Comment: @Brian: so, in total, I have $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!} \frac{7!}{2!2!}$ favorable cases.

Comment: @Javi: I take it back: it’s the first approach that is incorrect. It treats the accidents as indistinguishable, which they are not. To see this more clearly, imagine that there are just $2$ accidents, and we want the probability that they occur on the same day. That is clearly $\frac7{49}=\frac17$, but your first approach would make it $\frac7{28}=\frac14$.

Comment: Though I state it little differently, I get the same answer with your second approach. In the first approach that you are taking, it does not matter which accident happened when - you are using ${13 \choose 6}$ to find all possible sequences. In fact I am not sure of the first approach and whether each sequence is equally probable.

Comment: @Brian, Math Lover: thank you very much, this is indeed the case. In the easier $2$-accidents example, in my first approach the sequences $0000011$ and $0000002$ are treated as equally probable but they are not, since the first sequence could have been built with $a_1$ assigned to $F$ and $a_2$ to $Sa$ and viceversa, hence $2$ ways; whereas the second sequence implies both $a_1$ and $a_2$ assigned to $Sa$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is wrong, because the $1716$ sequences are not equiprobable. E.g., the sequence $a:=(7,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ is much less probable than the sequence $b:=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, because in $a$ you want every accident at the day of your liking, namely Sunday, while in $b$ there is no prescription which of the seven accidents happened on which day.